# How to resize (reduce) image in carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need help to reduce a picture so it could be nicely placed into carousel.
I made 2 pages with a slightly different carousel.

In first page it is placed nicely: [first carousel where picture if nicely placed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BMf5.jpg)

And on a second carousel with a slightly different look it looks like this: [second carousel where picture is too big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dICyU.jpg)

Codes for second carousel are (first CSS and second HTML)

```css
#thumbnail-preview-indicators {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-1,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-2,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-3,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-4,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-5,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-6,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-7,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-8,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-9,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-10,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-11{
  background-size: 50%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-1,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-2,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-3,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-4,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-5,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-6,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-7,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-8,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-9,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-10,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-11{
  height: 480px;
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-1{
  background-image: url(img/AudiA3.jpg);
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-2{
  background-image: url(img/AudiA3b.jpg);
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-3{
  background-image: url(img/AudiA3c.jpg);
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-4{
  background-image: url(img/AudiA3d.jpg);
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-5{
  background-image: url(img/AudiA3e.jpg);
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-6{
  background-image: url(img/AudiA3g.jpg);
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-7{
  background-image: url(img/AudiA3h.jpg);
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-8{
  background-image: url(img/AudiA3i.jpg);
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-9{
  background-image: url(img/AudiA3j.jpg);
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-10{
  background-image: url(img/AudiA3k.jpg);
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .slides .slide-11{
  background-image: url(img/AudiA3l.jpg);
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-inner .item .carousel-caption {
  top: 20%;
  bottom: inherit;
}

/* CAROUSEL INDICATORS */
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li.active {
  width: 102px;
  height: 69px;

  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 1px;
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li > .thumbnail {
  width: 100px;
  height: 66px;

  overflow: hidden;
  
  opacity: 0.8;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all 550ms ease-out;
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li:hover > .thumbnail,
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li.active > .thumbnail:hover {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1.5);
  z-index: 1;
}
#thumbnail-preview-indicators .carousel-indicators li.active > .thumbnail:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}



@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
}
```

```html
<div id="thumbnail-preview-indicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <!-- INDIKATORI -->

                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/AudiA3.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" data-slide-to="1">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/AudiA3b.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" data-slide-to="2">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/AudiA3c.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" data-slide-to="3">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/AudiA3d.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" data-slide-to="4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/AudiA3e.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" data-slide-to="5">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/AudiA3g.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" data-slide-to="6">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/AudiA3h.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" data-slide-to="7">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/AudiA3i.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" data-slide-to="8">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/AudiA3j.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" data-slide-to="9">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/AudiA3k.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li data-target="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" data-slide-to="10">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/AudiA3l.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ol>

                <!-- KRAJ NAVIGATORA-->


                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item slides active">
                        <div class="slide-1"><img src="img/AudiA3.jpg" alt="Audi A3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item slides">
                        <div class="slide-2"><img src="img/AudiA3b.jpg" alt="Audi A3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item slides">
                        <div class="slide-3"><img src="img/AudiA3c.jpg" alt="Audi A3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item slides">
                        <div class="slide-4"><img src="img/AudiA3d.jpg" alt="Audi A3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item slides">
                        <div class="slide-5"><img src="img/AudiA3e.jpg" alt="Audi A3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item slides">
                        <div class="slide-6"><img src="img/AudiA3g.jpg" alt="Audi A3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item slides">
                        <div class="slide-7"><img src="img/AudiA3h.jpg" alt="Audi A3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item slides">
                        <div class="slide-8"><img src="img/AudiA3i.jpg" alt="Audi A3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item slides">
                        <div class="slide-9"><img src="img/AudiA3j.jpg" alt="Audi A3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item slides">
                        <div class="slide-10"><img src="img/AudiA3k.jpg" alt="Audi A3"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item slides">
                        <div class="slide-11"><img src="img/AudiA3l.jpg" alt="Audi A3"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#thumbnail-preview-indicators" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
            </div>
```

So I hope that somebody knows how to fix this because I tried everythig.

Comment: Have you tried contain (either as a background-size or object-fit value).

Comment: I'm not sure what do you think?

Comment: What happens if you try it?

Comment: If I try what? I didn't understand what should I write?

Comment: Look up background-size contain and object-fit contain..

Comment: Ohh ok, I tried that now and nothing has changed